# How to change watchers order in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written one controller and directive with local scope.
I set watcher on scope variable in postLink method and added $interval for changing variable, also I added watcher on binded variable in my controller.

```
console.clear();
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

       $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.ctrlVar;
    }, function(newValue) {
      console.log('WATCHER TWO: newValue = ', newValue);
    }, true);

  }
]);

myApp.directive('testDirective', 
 ['$interval', function($interval) {
    return {
      scope: {
        date: '=dateModel'
      },
      template: "<input type='text' value='{{date}}' />",
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element) {
        console.log('link');
        var i = 1;
        $interval(function() {
              scope.date = i++;

        }, 1000);

          scope.$watch('date', function(){
          console.log('WATCHER ONE: newValue = ', scope.date);
        });

      }
    };
  }]
);
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <test-directive date-model="ctrlVar"></test-directive>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I see that order on invoking watch listeners is

```
WATCHER IN CONTROLLER: newValue =  undefined
script.js:32 WATCHER IN DIRECTIVE: newValue =  undefined
script.js:32 WATCHER IN DIRECTIVE: newValue =  1
script.js:10 WATCHER IN CONTROLLER: newValue =  1
script.js:32 WATCHER IN DIRECTIVE: newValue =  2
script.js:10 WATCHER IN CONTROLLER: newValue =  2
```

I noticed that when the newValue is changed in $interval watch listener in the directive is called at first. In my production code (I didn't post code because it's a little bit complicated and I create plunk and behaviour of a watcher is different).

Do you know how to manage an order of watch listeners? Is it possible?

Here is example http://plnkr.co/edit/QzeZar?p=preview

Comment: Please post the actual code in the question. The question should stand on its own without relying on external links

Comment: If behavior is different in production than demo, how will demo help us understand your issue? Also what is the actual problem that the watch is producing?

Comment: take a look at options  `priority` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: I think that if this is a problem, then you need to rethink your solution. The order that watchers call should not cause issues; if this race condition is causing problems, it likely means that your business logic is scattered, too fragile.

Comment: what is it that you are trying to accomplish with these watchers? your sample doesn't really demonstrate why this is even necessary.  This feels like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @DRobinson, but if you absolutely must change the order fo the watchers, you may be able to use timeouts to set a sort of 'priority' to your watchers. I don't know of any way to change the watchers after they have been registered, but you can delay registering them.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $scope.ctrlVar;
        }, function (newValue) {
            console.log('WATCHER TWO: newValue = ', newValue);
        }, true);
   }, 10);

}]);
```

Here's a fiddle showing that watcher two fires AFTER watcher one the first time. http://jsfiddle.net/qj7gn5x4/1/